# Angular Integration - HTTP Client

Tags: javascript, json, angular, rest, http

I'm not sure how to integrate my restful API´s with the HTTP Angular client, this is my HTTP Angular client implementation:

```
getList(): Promise<any> {
this.http.get<any>(this.url).toPromise()
  .then(
  data =>  {
    console.log(data);
  }
);
```

And this is my API JSON response structure:

```
{
    "eeeeee": {
        "qqq": [
            {
                "aaa": "fff",
                "zzz": "bbb",
                "yyy": "mmm",
                "xxx": "nnn"
            },
            {
                "aaa": "aaa",
                "zzz": "zzzz",
                "yyy": "yyyy",
                "xxx": "ccc"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-get-examples check this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an service for your API calls e.g **apiService**, then using your service in every component that you want. In addition, it's recommended to use **Observables** instead of **Promises**. So, Try something like this:

**api.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  private REST_API_SERVER = "http://localhost:3000";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getList(): Promise<any> {
     return this.http.get<any>(this.url);
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  public list: any;

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.apiService.getList().subscribe((data: any[])=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.list= data;
    })  
  }

}
```

Comment: Hey @ng-hobby,
I already have a service in my angular app and in the previous version of my app I used Observables, the problem is, I had the necessity to change my  rest API response, before my api returned a List but now returns a Map<String, Object[]>
Above I posted my API JSON example, like you posted it will not work, because DATA is and object that have an object inside, and in this second object it has an array list

Comment: Ok, what's the problem? in your Components you cant get the inner object by `data.eeeeee` e.g. `console.log(data.eeeeee)` or get the array and do any process that you want. If you think you will have more transformation on your data you can use a second service as a factory and do the processing staff there